# Should All Class References in a Serializable Object Implement Serializable?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to save the neural network after training  by implementing a Serializable object, and this class contains Layer and Node class references.
My question is: should I implement Serializable in these(layer,node) two classes as well, in order to be able to save and load instances of the Neural Network class successfully without any problem, especially { java.io.NotSerializableException } ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every object that you intend to store/load using serialization must implement `Serializable`.  This includes any member fields inside the objects that you are serializing.

The only exception are fields that you don't think that you will need to store for later use when you deserialize.  You can mark these fields as "transient," e.g.

```
private transient int foo;
```

Any field marked as transient will NOT be stored as part of the serialized object, and when the object is later deserialized will be set to the default value (i.e. 0 for most primitives, false for booleans, and null for objects).